# Change the focused control on Inno Setup start

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

How can I change the focused control on welcome page? It is currently focused on `NextButton`. But I need to change it to `CancelButton` (or even any other buttons which I have added them programmatically like an About Button)

I tried this on `InitializeWizard` event:

```pascal
WizardForm.ActiveControl := CancelButton;
CancelButton.Default := true;
```

but no success. Even I tried something described here: http://www.delphigroups.info/2/f3/324879.html

```pascal
SendMessage(Handle, WM_NEXTDLGCTL, 0, 0 );
```

and no success.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing wizard's `ActiveControl` in `InitializeWizard` is too early. It will get changed afterwards to the *Next* button.

Do it in the [`CurPageChanged(wpWelcome)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurPageChanged):

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpWelcome then
    WizardForm.ActiveControl := WizardForm.CancelButton;
end;
```